# Graphs with vertices consisting of all strings, which share an edge if they differ on all coordinates

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Let $\Sigma$ be some alphabet, and let $j$ be an integer.

I'm interested in the graph $G$ in which $V(G)$ is the set of all strings of length $j$ over $\Sigma$, and two strings share an edge if they differ on every coordinate.  That, $s$ and $t$ share an edge if $s[i] \neq t[i]$ for every $1 \leq i \leq j$.

This graph is quite simple if $\Sigma$ is the binary alphabet, but gets complicated quickly.

I want to know if this graph has been mentioned in the literature.  Does it have a name?  Does it belong to a special class of graphs?  Any kind of information that would've been published.

Comment: The most trivial case is $|\Sigma| = 1 \ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This graph is a member of an association scheme, the Hamming scheme
$H(j,|\Sigma|)$. From this it's possible, for example, to derive expressions for the eigenvalues; it has the same eigenvectors as the Hamming graph.

The Hamming scheme can be viewed as the set of graphs with vertex set $\Sigma^j$, where two strings are adjacent in $r$-th graph if and only
If they differ in exactly $r$ positions.